Condition on the transition kernel to get a surjective Markov Operator
Let $T : L^1(\nu) \to L^1(\mu)$ be a an operator, where $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures (the distributions of random variables $X$ and $Y$, respectively), defined as:
$$
(Tf)(x) = \int f(y) \ k(x, dy) \quad (= \int f(y) \ \pi_{X=x}(dy), \text{ where } \pi \text{ is the joint distribution of } (X, Y)).
$$
Thus $T$ is a Markov operator.
Leading me to the question : are there conditions on the transition kernel $k$ (in my case on the joint distribution) for a Markov operator $T$ to be surjective?
